# ByTeArray AS3 function from C# function help needed

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I am a noob with ByteArray use in as3 and would need some help.
I am trying to reproduce this "Header" function in as3 returning a ByteArray from a C# function (code provided bellow). 
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I got to this point and not sure how to continue:

```
 private function header():ByteArray
    {
        var header:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        header.writeUTFBytes("A");
        header.writeUTFBytes("B");
        header.writeUTFBytes("C");
        header.writeUTFBytes("D");
            ...                
    }
```

Thank you

```cs
private enum PacketType
    {
        PtHelo = 0x01,
        PtBye = 0x02,
        PtButton = 0x03,
        PtMouse = 0x04,
    }

private const byte bv = 2;
private const byte mv = 0;

private byte[] Header(PacketType packetType, int numberOfPackets, int currentPacket, int payloadSize)
    {
        var header = new byte[HeaderSize];
        header[0] = (byte)'A';
        header[1] = (byte)'B';
        header[2] = (byte)'C';
        header[3] = (byte)'D';
        header[4] = bv;
        header[5] = mv;
        if (currentPacket == 1)
        {
            header[6] = (byte)(((ushort)packetType & 0xff00) >> 8);
            header[7] = (byte)((ushort)packetType & 0x00ff);
        }
        else
        {
            header[6] = ((ushort)PacketType.PtBlob & 0xff00) >> 8;
            header[7] = (ushort)PacketType.PtBlob & 0x00ff;
        }
        header[8] = (byte)((currentPacket & 0xff000000) >> 24);
        header[9] = (byte)((currentPacket & 0x00ff0000) >> 16);
        header[10] = (byte)((currentPacket & 0x0000ff00) >> 8);
        header[11] = (byte)(currentPacket & 0x000000ff);
        header[12] = (byte)((numberOfPackets & 0xff000000) >> 24);
        header[13] = (byte)((numberOfPackets & 0x00ff0000) >> 16);
        header[14] = (byte)((numberOfPackets & 0x0000ff00) >> 8);
        header[15] = (byte)(numberOfPackets & 0x000000ff);
        header[16] = (byte)((payloadSize & 0xff00) >> 8);
        header[17] = (byte)(payloadSize & 0x00ff);
        return header;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rest of your header function can basically use the same array indices and bit arithmetic as the C# version (removing only the casts).  But it might be simpler to avoid the arithmetic:

```
header.endian = Endian.BIG_ENDIAN; // important for writing multibyte below
header.writeUTFBytes('ABCD');
header.writeByte(bv);
header.writeByte(mv);
if (...) {
    header.writeShort(packetType);
} else {
    header.writeShort(PtBlob); // PtBlob is a constant defined elsewhere
}
header.writeInt(currentPacket);
...
```

---

Using the byte arithmetic:

```
header.writeByte((packetType & 0xff00) >> 8);
header.writeByte(packetType & 0x00ff);
```

Since the above is writing two bytes from `packetType`, it's equivalent to a big-endian `writeShort()`.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I will try this.

Comment: If I want to do the bit arithmetic ... how would i do that in as3?

Comment: Thank you so much.. i'm still working on it and not getting the result i need... in order to get private const byte bv = 2; ... header[4] = bv; to AS3 is this header.writeByte(2); or header.writeInt(2); ???